# Is it possible to apply the same UPDATE logic to multiple columns in a single statement in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I use MySQL 8.0 and I'm trying to change empty strings to NULLs in a table that has many columns.

I was wondering if there's a more intelligent way to apply the same UPDATE logic to multiple columns, in a single statement.

So instead of:

```
UPDATE tbl SET col1 = NULL WHERE col1 = '';  
UPDATE tbl SET col2 = NULL WHERE col2 = '';  
UPDATE tbl SET col3 = NULL WHERE col3 = '';
```

Something like:

```
UPDATE tbl SET <multiple_columns> = NULL WHERE <multiple_columns> = '';
```

Minimal dataset to work with:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (col1 TEXT, col2 TEXT, col3 TEXT);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ('', 'B', 'C'), ('A', '', 'C'), ('A', 'B', '');
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in single query by using `case` expression but you need to apply this for each column

```
UPDATE tbl 
SET col1 = case when col1 = '' then null else col1 end,
col2 = case when col2 = '' then null else col2 end,
col3 = case when col3 = '' then null else col3 end;
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fe3118/1)

Comment: @Y-M I also would add `WHERE
 col1 = '' OR col2 = '' OR col3 = ''` if the columns are indexed so MySQL can use the indexes on the columns... And in MySQL `case when col1 = '' then null else col1 end` can also be rewitten as `if(col1 = '', null, col1)`

Comment: Thanks Khalid and Raymond but that logic duplication is exactly what I'm trying to avoid since I have a lot of columns...